# Force ASP.NET compilation to use a fresh (non-cached) version of a master page

Tags: asp.net, caching, compilation, master-pages

I have a master page embedded in an assembly and served through a virtual path provider.  (/_v/name.space.myMaster.master)

Changes to the master are not being reflected in the web application, and I am getting, in this specific case, an error related to a missing ContentPlaceHolder.  I remedied the error (ruant="server" rather than runat="server") and yet, I still get the error.

I have turned on .master as an allowed extension, and have confirmed that the file served through the VPP differs from the file embedded in the assembly (I inspected the assembly via Reflector).

I have done cleans/re-builds in VS, and have gone so far as to nuke my "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder in both the 64/non-64 flavors.  Is there something else I need to do to force a recompilation from a non-cached version of the master page?

Comment: Are you able to restart the web site on IIS?

Comment: Absolutely, that was one of the first things that I tried.

Comment: Deleting your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and restarting IIS should have cleared anything that was cached. Perhaps there's some other problem with your code?

Comment: @MichaelLiu: That was the behavior I was expecting, yes.  What leads me away from thinking that this is a code problem is that the assembly that contains the embedded master, and the VPP is GAC'd (post-build re-GAC), and the web application that implements the VPP is referencing the GAC'd assembly.  Examining the GAC'd assembly in Reflector, it has the fixed version embedded, but the IIS AppDomain keeps serving up the unfixed version despite iisresets and nuking "Temporary ASP.NET files."  I have not gone so far as to remove and recreate the site in IIS, but that might be my next step.

Comment: I recommend running [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see where ASP.NET is loading your DLL from.

Comment: I found a solution, and added it as an answer below, but I cannot confirm it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly, though GAC'd was never removed from the bin folder of the web application, despite running a clean on that project in VS.

Removing the copy of the assembly from the bin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your VirtualPathProvider class you can override the method [GetCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.getcachedependency.aspx) to specify a dependency that monitors a file.

```
public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, 
  System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, 
  DateTime utcStart)
    // Get the physical path to the assembly
    return new CacheDependency(path_to_assembly);
}
```

This [dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tfwsbfk.aspx) will be used by ASP.NET to cache the object. Since the dependency tracks a physical file, whenever that file changes ASP.NET will remove the object from the cache.

Comment: I have already overriden GetCacheDependency() similarly, though I had to account for multiple assemblies.